# Regex for greping C type definition

Tags: c, regex, grep

I have a big bunch of source files and I want to grep through it to find the definition of a specific user-defined type `dev_if_type_t`. All I know about it so far it's that some functions in the code I'm examining use it as a return value.

Right now I'm using the following:

```
typedef.*dev_if_type_t|(define|typedef|enum|struct)\s*dev_if_type_t
```

but it returns no results. Is there another method of  C type definition I'm neglecting to mention?

The grep line itself, in the code base's top directory:

```
grep -rn "typedef.*dev_if_type_t\|\(define\|typedef\|enum\|struct\)\s*dev_if_type_t" *
```

Comment: If there's something I could do to improve the question or a reason you think it's a bad question, please let me know...

Comment: Can you show how you are trying to `grep` through these files?

Comment: @hwnd, edited to add to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There could be much more variants of the definition like:

```c
typedef struct {
    /* some code */
} dev_if_type_t;
```

Some code could also look like this:

```c
#define \
dev_if_type_t int

struct
dev_if_type_t
{
    /* some code */
};
```

You'll never know.
I would suggest you try it just with grepping `dev_if_type_t` and using the context option `-C <num>`of `grep` to find the definition by yourself.

When using expressions including `|` don't forget to use `egrep` (deprecated) or the proper command `grep -E ...`.

Note that `\|` and `\(` has a different meaning. Use `|` and `(` for your purpose.

So the correct pattern should be:

```
grep -Ern "typedef.*dev_if_type_t|(define|typedef|enum|struct)\s*dev_if_type_t" *
```

Comment: The multiline problems can be at least partially resolved using pcregrep, though.